# Number of seeds per torrent

Tags: bittorrent

I am looking for a program that can return the number of seeds per torrent given a list of torrent files. It should not start downloading the files the torrents contain.

The program can run on Mac OS X, Microsoft  Windows or Linux. Any license or price is fine. CLI or GUI is fine as well, but it should be able to handle at least a few hundred torrent files. Ideally it should return the number of peers as well.